# Why FileStream.Length is long type, but FileStream.Read argument - offset has a shorter length?

Tags: c#

Why FileStream.Length is long type, but FileStream.Read argument - offset has a shorter length int instead?

Bryan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `offset` parameter tells where to start writing data in your array, the `array` parameter. It does not point out an offset in the file data.

> The *offset* parameter gives the offset of the byte in *array* (the buffer index) at which to begin reading, and the *count* parameter gives the maximum number of bytes to be read from this stream. The returned value is the actual number of bytes read, or zero if the end of the stream is reached. If the read operation is successful, the current position of the stream is advanced by the number of bytes read. If an exception occurs, the current position of the stream is unchanged.

Source: [FileStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

The offset is the index into the byte array where the data is placed. You can't allocate an array that is larger than 2 GB, so there is no need for a bigger number for the offset.

Comment: This is allowed in .NET 4.5 with configuration. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SimonSvensson: That changes the limit for arrays in general, but it doesn't change the limit for a single dimension byte array. *"The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays"*

Answer (score 2):

As addition to mike z answer, why byte[] cannot be indexed more than int.MaxValue - class Array implements IList with `object this[int index] { get; set; }` method, so index can be only integer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are referring to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) method which is overridden from the base class `Stream`.

The offset is the location in the `array` argument to place the bytes not the offset from the beginning of the `FileStream`. The `array` argument is of type `byte[]` which cannot have more than `int.MaxValue` elements.

Answer (score 1):

FileStream.Length gets the length in bytes of the stream and FileStream.Read reads a block of bytes from the stream. So, logically you'll have more single bytes than blocks of that bytes. I'm assuming that for this reason FileStream.Length requires long type.

Answer (score 0):

FileStream extending Stream,

Stream can handle number of byte[int.MaxValue] arrays and together they have a long length.

But when you use Read, you can read only part of it to a byte array with int.MaxValue.

Think about that if you want to read from disk a file bigger then 2G = int.MaxValue ,
you will need to read it in chunks of byte[int.MaxValue]

(: